# Building a voltage transformer circuit for sensing mains voltage

Tags: transformer, mains

I would like to create a safe electrical circuit that measures the voltage from the wall (220vac). And the safest way that i know of so that when something fails there would be a high chance that my electronics could still survive is by using a step down transformer.

The circuit i have came up with looks like this

[image]

I have several problems though:

1. Im having trouble looking for a transformer, since its for voltage sensing only i dont really need highoutput current, but most important of all it must be as small as possible so that i can place it on my pcb. I even opted for smd only to ensure that there will be no arc going onto another pcb on the bottom. But even with that there seems to be a lot type of transformers and dont know which one will work. Here are the three types that i think will likely to work. [SMPS](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/transformers/switching-converter-smps-transformers/168?k=transformers&k=&pkeyword=transformers&sv=0&sf=1&FV=69%7C409393%2C183%7C348876%2C1393%7C101053%2C1393%7C101237%2C1393%7C105475%2C1393%7C107488%2C1393%7C110367%2C1393%7C110384%2C1393%7C114142%2C1393%7C114145%2C1393%7C114149%2C1393%7C115124%2C1393%7C115251%2C1393%7C115554%2C1393%7C118747%2C1393%7C118917%2C1393%7C118919%2C1393%7C139643%2C1393%7C140848%2C1393%7C145598%2C1393%7C150722%2C1393%7C156580%2C1393%7C157722%2C1393%7C160621%2C1393%7C164265%2C1393%7C195578%2C1393%7C200719%2C1393%7C220623%2C1393%7C235567%2C1393%7C255077%2C1393%7C272412%2C1393%7C277003%2C1393%7C279456%2C1393%7C285629%2C1393%7C285649%2C1393%7C285654%2C1393%7C290354%2C1393%7C290376%2C1393%7C290377%2C1393%7C290398%2C1393%7C290438%2C1393%7C290455%2C1393%7C290464%2C1393%7C290469%2C1393%7C290474%2C1393%7C292620%2C1393%7C298705%2C1393%7C298713%2C1393%7C298739%2C1393%7C301979%2C1393%7C302718%2C1393%7C302719%2C1393%7C433702%2C1393%7C67527%2C1393%7C67533%2C1393%7C78532%2C1393%7C78969%2C1393%7C83228%2C1393%7C83229%2C1393%7C83245%2C1393%7C83246%2C1393%7C83247%2C1393%7C83248%2C1393%7C83253%2C1393%7C84289%2C1393%7C85320%2C1393%7C86084%2C1393%7C86087%2C1393%7C86088%2C1393%7C90237%2C1989%7C0%2C-8%7C168%2C7%7C17%2C7%7C2&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=100), [Pulse](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/transformers/pulse-transformers/166?k=transformers&k=&pkeyword=transformers&sv=0&pv69=409393&sf=1&FV=-8%7C166%2C1989%7C0&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=100), [Current](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/transformers/current-sense-transformers/163?k=transformers&k=&pkeyword=transformers&sv=0&sf=1&FV=-8%7C163%2C69%7C409393%2C1989%7C0&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=100).

   The SMPS seems to be the most likely i will be using having high isolation and its actually stated that it can handle 220VAC. I am having second thoughts on the other tweo because some of them does not say on the datasheet the max voltage the input can handle.
2. For the value of the voltage divider, to get the desired output voltage that my differential ADC can handle. getting the ratio of the resistor is simple. But i am not sure what the values should be should i go higher or lower? In the circuit above i used 1k and 0.5k but i can also be 10k and 5k. which would be better?
3. A gut feeling is telling me that my circuit seems to be only good on paper, and in real world there would be more components,? what should i add to this circuit to make more like a proper circuit that can survive in the real world. Heck how do industrial grade equipment do their single phase voltage sensing.

Comment: The SMPS link takes you to a page where there are several different types hence, you need to specifically state which model number. In fact, now that I've seen that page in more detail, it's clear that none of them can handle 220 volt AC unless it's at several tens of kHz i.e. they'll detonate at 50 or 60 Hz.

Comment: For a 50/60Hz mains transformer, about the lowest power you'll find is 3W, and that'll be something like an inch cube.

Comment: If you need any decent amount of accuracy and are planning to use an ADC to look at the voltage then I would consider [my answer here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/209405/voltage-sensing-using-arduino-with-and-without-common-reference/209408).

Comment: @Andyaka oh so transformers must be operated at their frequency range, Thank you that would be a great reference, is the 24 bit ADC overkill? 5volts at 24bits is 0.000000298 thats a lot of zeros, 16bit is 0.0000763 which i think is still okay, I do not have a frame of reference so i cant tell. Before i get to that i might have a problem looking for a transformer.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Do think you can link me to one sir? or maybe what type, i dont mind a 1inch cube, i dont want the transformer weight breaking my board in half.

Comment: You can search for a 3W 50z transformer as efficiently as I can.

Comment: @BrianDrummond under these [selection](https://bit.ly/2WqpJGv) this one seems to be the smallest that i think will work is [this one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/hammond-manufacturing/160D10/HM4117-ND/455009) , its rated 5v(parallel) which eleminnates the use of the voltage divider, can i trust it though that it wont go beyond?

Comment: 5V means 5V RMS or about 7V peak. And unloaded, that may rise to about 8V. (16V peak to peak) Also your ADC probably requires an input signal between 0 and 5V (negative or over-range may damage it) so desin your attenuator around these constraints.

Comment: You don't need to use that exact ADC - many, many others can fit the interface requirements if you need decent accuracy and decent resolution.

Comment: @BrianDrummond if in differential mode shouldnt i be able to measure -5 to 5v (Vcc=5)? Now that you mentioned it when i check the ADC that i have used there is no mention of maximum voltage range in differential mode. I have done measuring a 3VAC before, and the chip seems to be fine.

Comment: A digital voltmeter, pluggable in a 2 pin socket, would cost around $ 8.00.

Comment: @vu2nan its for a microcontroller so that the data read will be used for something else

Comment: Many thanks for the information, DrakeJest.

Comment: Hi DrakeJest, Please look for 'miniature 230V instrument isolation transformers'.

Comment: I could not find a smaller one than the [one i already found](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/hammond-manufacturing/160D10/HM4117-ND/455009) with a dimention of 25cm by 35cm. Of cour

Comment: DrakeJest, You mean 25mm x 35mm?

Comment: @Andyaka The question that you closed as duplicate is NOT a duplicate - it is a superset of this one. As I know you know. It asks a wider and useful question. If anything this question is the redundant one. Closing the other prevents both useful and cautionary comment on the new material.